# How can get a members length if active property is true in ngFor

Tags: angular

I have a array of objects and in ngFor I want to get the the members count if the member in a team is active. Like in below example first members array has 2 members but only one is active so I should get length or count 1, in second members array there are 2 members and both are active so counet should be 2. Is it possible to get it using ngFor or there is any other way. Any help is appreciated.

```
{
"name": "Team 1",   
"members": [{           
        "active": true,
        "fullName": "TEST",
        "teamId": "xxx"         
    }, {            
        "active": false,
        "fullName": "ghgfhfghgfh"
    }
],
"childTeam": [{
        "name": "CTeam1",
        "members": [{                   
                "active": true,
                "fullName": "fghfhgfh"
            }, {                    
                "active": true,
                "fullName": "retweew"
            }
        ]
    },{
        "name": "CTeam2",
        "members": [{                   
                "active": true,
                "fullName": "fghfhgfh"
            }, {                    
                "active": true,
                "fullName": "retweew"
            },
            {                   
                "active": true,
                "fullName": "ddgfdgd"
            }
        ]
       } 
    ]
}
```

And I am using it in ngFor as below -

```
    <div *ngFor="let membs of node.data.members; let i = index">
  <div *ngIf="membs.active && node.data.members.length === 1">
    <div class="pull-left leadIcon">
      <mat-icon *ngIf="membs.active">person</mat-icon>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="membs.active && node.data.members.length > 1">
    <div class="pull-left"> {{ node.data.members.length }}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you filter like this `yourArray.filter((item,i) => { return item.active; }).length`

Comment: Actually I need this length inside my template while using ngFor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way on HTML

```
 <div *ngIf="node.data.members.length >= 1">
    <div class="pull-left"> {{getActives()}}</div>
 </div>
```

Do in TS:

```
getActives(){
   return this.node.data.members.filter(member => member.active == true).length;
  }
```

Plunkr without material working fine:

https://plnkr.co/edit/w8mFjK1puVApgczcHVEE

Comment: I am actually looping over this team object using ngFor and I need this in the ngFor loop. Above solution is not for ngFor I guess.

Comment: I am getting error saying "Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Bindings cannot contain assignments"

Comment: This works..!!! great thanks. This is really a nice way of implementing or iterating in ngFor. Thanks a lot...!!!

Comment: You'r wellcome. You must to know functions in html side is not the most efficient. You can calculate this data when you get from backend and show in one variable too.

Comment: Sure, that makes more sense though.